# Variable not replacing one of parameters in function

Tags: python, function

I have a function and I am trying to pass a global variable through it. The rest of the function works, but when yards1 <= 0 , userscore still == 0.

My assumption was that 7 is being added to whoScore, but I thought since whoScore was a parameter, like x, that it would be replaced by userscore. I am looking for a way to make it so userscore or oppscore can be placed into the function for touchdowns.

I have tried renaming the parameter to a single letter, z.  Did not work

I have printed whoScore and have seen that in fact, 7 is being added to whoScore and not userscore.

```
userscore = 0
oppscore = 0

def runSuccess(text, x, y, whoScore):

    global yards1

    global distance

    global down

    global userscore

    global oppscore

    yardschange1 = random.randint(x, y)
    print(text, "Gain of ", yardschange1, "yards!")
    yards1 -= yardschange1
    down += 1
    distance -= yardschange1
    if yards1 <= 0:
        print("TOUCHDOWN!")
        whoScore += 7
        print("")
        print(whoScore)
        print(userteam, ":", userscore, oppteam, ":", oppscore)

runSuccess("blah", 1, 5, userscore)
```

I expected userscore to replace whoScore in the function because they are in the same place in the parentheses, and userscore == 7. However, whoScore is ran through the function and whoScore == 7.

Comment: Seems you may want to lookup the difference between a local variable and a global variable.

Comment: I understand that local variables are defined inside the function and global variables are defined outside the function. I guess I'm just confused why my "blah" will replace text, 1 will replace x, 5 will replace y, but userscore won't replace whoScore

Answer (score 1):

add userscore = whoScore under the whoScore += 1 line at the if statement if you want to change the global value of userscore. the  'userscore' you past to runSuccess() was treat as a whoScore inside the function, which means it is different from userscore.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to make it so I can use the function to change the value of userscore or oppscore or would I just have to make one function for each. Because, you solution sounds like the function would then just change the value of userscore. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @KiddMoney def runSuccess(text, x, y), keep the global statement and replace the whoScore with userscore inside the function.

Comment: @KiddMoney Actually, after global userscore, oppscore,  whatever value you give to user score or oppscore inside the function would be changed outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise  the variable and then you can use it .
like this :

```
import numpy as np
userscore = 0
oppscore = 0
yards1=0
distance=0
down=0
def runSuccess(text, x, y, whoScore):

  global yards1

  global distance

  global down

  global userscore

  global oppscore

  yardschange1 = np.random.randint(x, y)
  print(text, "Gain of ", yardschange1, "yards!")
  yards1 -= yardschange1
  down += 1
  distance -= yardschange1
  if yards1 <= 0:
      print("TOUCHDOWN!")
      whoScore += 7
      print("")
      print(whoScore)
      print('userteam', ":", userscore, 'oppteam', ":", oppscore)

    runSuccess("blah", 1, 5, userscore)
```